# FLEX inserting an object to a data grid

Tags: apache-flex, flashbuilder4

whenever i insert an object to this datagrid it show this error

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Forms::LessonPlan/addLesson_clickHandler()

this is my code
for inserting an object

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
var temp:Object = new Object();
obj.activityid = arrayNames.selectedItem.activityid;
obj.lessonid = getLessonIDResult.lastResult ;
obj.time = durationCombo.selectedItem;
obj.status = "active";
obj.activityname = arrayNames.selectedItem.activityname;
temp = ({activityname:obj.activityname,time:obj.time});
studentLessonPlanArray.addItem(temp);
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing at what line the error occurs, and assuming that `arrayNames` and `studentLessonPlanArray` are properly initialized, it seems that there is no item selected in the List/DataGrid named `arrayNames`.

Comment: well actually arrayNames is a combo box and i tried to do an alert statement to show the value of the selectedItem but it does show the right value of what i selected

Comment: the error was on the last line. the line studentLessonPlanArray.addItem(temp)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the the reference(studentLessonPlanArray) is instantiated before it is called. Also check [this](http://blog.flexcommunity.net/?p=36) link.